Update some fields without transferring full model from view
I have model (ApplicationUser : Identity user) and I want to update several fields, but if I do not create the remaining fields of model (PasswordHash, PhoneNumber and etc.) then null is passed instead.
 <div class="form-floating py-1 col-12">
      <input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control boarder-0 shadow" />
      <label asp-for="Email" class="ms-2"></label>
      <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-floating py-1 col-12">
      <input asp-for="UserName" type="text" class="form-control boarder-0 shadow" />
      <label asp-for="UserName" class="ms-2"></label>
      <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>

if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     _unitOfWork.ApplicationUser.Update(userObj);
     _unitOfWork.Save();
 }

What is the best way to transfer only these changes, and fill the rest with what already exists and is not transferred from the view?

It is a bad way to use the database table on the front. It would be best if you used mapping your database entity to view the model(or DTO) with concrete fields for update

Oh, but this is Admin area for user management. For visitors, I use a viewmodel with pre-prepared data. Or is it bad for the admin too? Is it possible to show an example/pattern of a more correct way?

in my opinion it is also bad idea
